# Flex getApplicationVersion() always returns null version

Tags: flash, apache-flex, installation, air

I'm currently working on a Flash application that has a sibling AIR equivalent. From inside the Flash application I would like to install the sibling AIR App. Adobe has provided an air.swf (which is also used in the Badge sample) to aid us with the install. I've managed to mimic the behavior of the Badge app but getApplicationVersion always returns null. Note that I do not have a publisherId.

Here's the documentation provided by Adobe: [Installing and running an AIR applications from a web page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html)

Air application XML:

```
...

< id >MyAirApplication< /id >

...
```

Now I'm trying to find out the application version using the following:

```
public function DoAction(event:MouseEvent):void 
{
   try {
      m_airSwf.getApplicationVersion( "MyAirApplication", "", CheckVersion_);
   }
   catch(e:Error) { ... }
}

private function CheckVersion_(version : String):void
{
   Alert.show("Version: " + version); // Always returns null
}
```

Now the CheckVersion_ function is called and the version that is passed in is always null. I've checked the log and I've found this entry:

> [2011-02-08:09:29:14] Commandline is:
>   -playerVersion=10,1,53,64 -sandboxType=remote -securityDomain=airdownload.adobe.com -https=false -fromUserEvent=true -- -launch MyAirApplication

I'm clearly missing something here. My actions seem pretty straight forward and I can't seem to pin point why it's not finding my application. Does anyone have any idea? Oh I've also tested on Windows 7 64bit, and Windows XP (to test permissions).

Comment: I've found out my issue. It wasn't quite clear but in order to launch OR query the AIR application you require the following in your application.xml
<allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>

Comment: hi etienne, for archiving/search purposes, instead of commenting the answer, please answer your own question with the "Your Answer" text area below and mark as answered if you've discovered the solution.

Comment: Etienne, just out of curiosity, where did you find this information? It is correct (so add your answer and get some more rep!), but I couldn't find any mention of the requirement in Adobe's documentation, specifically this: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found out my issue. It wasn't quite clear but in order to launch OR query the AIR application you require the following in your application.xml

```
<allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>
```