# Problems detecting installed AIR 2.x apps from Flash Badge

Tags: flash, air

I'm using the flash badge to attempt to detect whether an AIR application is installed. I've been unable to do so successfully using the air.swf loaded from http://airdownload.adobe.com/air/browserapi/air.swf.

The callback from getApplicationVersion() always results in a null string. I've tried building the target AIR app as both AIR 2.0 and AIR 2.5, both with the same result. The app in question is currently self-signed.

I've added debugging calls into the Flash badge so I know that the correct appID is being used. Why does getApplicationVersion always result in null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found another SO question with the answer in one of the comments:
[Flex getApplicationVersion() always returns null version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4936458/flex-getapplicationversion-always-returns-null-version)

The problem is that browser invocation needs to be enabled in order for getApplicationVersion() to be able to retrieve the value. The target application must have the following line in its application descriptor file:

```
<allowBrowserInvocation>true</allowBrowserInvocation>
```

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find this mentioned in [Adobe's documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html), though it does say that the setting is required in order to be able to launch the app from the browser.